# how does the sql statement work in remote server after typed in local PC?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I used DataGrip to connect a Postgresql database on a remote server. I chose 'open console' and typed a statement (CREATE INDEX, specificlly) to update the database(not query). It took a long time to execute. Can I just close DataGrip? Will the statement still work on the remote server even after I closed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily wind up with an invalid index (won't hurt anything except take up space)

Your index build could take forever because of activity in the table.

It's suggested to build index concurrently so the table can still be used while the index is being built.

```
 CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY
```